# Not all of the Form validation errors shown in JSP

Tags: java, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following code for validation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/itemValidation.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationResponse ajaxValidation(
            @ModelAttribute(value = formName) @Valid Item item,
            BindingResult result) {
        ValidationResponse res = new ValidationResponse();
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        } else {
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            List<FieldError> allErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
            List<ErrorMessage> errorMesages = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
            for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
                errorMesages.add(new ErrorMessage(objectError.getField(),
                        objectError.getDefaultMessage()));
            }
            res.setErrorMessageList(errorMesages);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Upon validation there are three elements which do not satisfy the constraints as shown below:

[image: FTIR in Biometrics]

The problem is on the JSP only the last two of the errors are shown. The error with fieldName : `itemPK.name` is not shown.

I use the below code to show the errors:

```
<span class="help-inline"><form:errors path="${name}" /></span>
```

My generated input elements in sequence:

```
<input id="itemPK.name_id" name="itemPK.name" type="text" value="">
<input id="price_id" name="price" type="number" value="">
<input id="point_id" name="point" type="number" value="">
```

Not sure what went wrong, hope anyone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was . There's another layer where an ajax response method suppose to append all the error messages to the appropriate fields. The first error was never shown due to the jQuery selector unable to locate element with name `itemPK.name`, the fix was to change  it to `itemPK\\.name`.

Answer (score 1):

If you said that last 2 field errors are displayed then you are probably have wrong name of the first field. Use

```
<form:input path="name" /><span class="help-inline"><form:errors path="name" /></span>
```

or use the path value `itemPK.name` that is reflect to your field name in the debug window.

Comment: The path name has been pointing to `itemPK.name`. Changing it to `name`  does not fix anything since its a non-existent property in the modelAttribute.